# How do you set the primary graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card

I recently installed a second graphics card on my computer so that I could have a dual-monitor setup. But when I start my computer, the second graphics card gets booted first. Is there any way to change this so that the card the was originally installed get booted first instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what interface you are using for the cards (PCI-E, AGP, etc) your BIOS may contain settings for prioritizing one slot over the other.

If all else fails, switch the physical location of the cards in the motherboard :)

Answer (score 1):

Most BIOSes for motherboards with an onboard hard have an option where you can pick onboard, PCI, or PCIe.